# Finding factors s.t. f(x) > g(x)

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-functions

I am looking forward for an answer to the following question: 
I have a function $f(x) = 1 - e^{-(x / \lambda)^k}$ . I want to find $\lambda'$ and $k'$ in $g(x)$ such that $g(x) < f(x) \in \mathbb{N}$. The constraint being that $k' \geq k$ and $\lambda' \leq \lambda$. I am strugguling on finding the minimum values of $\lambda'$ and $k'$ such that we always have $f(x) > g(x)$.

Anyone could lend me a hand on that? Many thanks.

Comment: What's $g(x)$? Can't help you without that one

Comment: $g(x)$ is the same as $f(x)$, only different by $\lambda'$ and $k'$

Comment: Then write it in the question